# Hiding div in mobile-view not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML website in which I am trying to hide a div containing images in mobile view.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #kingg { display: none !important; }

}
```

```html
<div id="kingg" class="grid-uniform section-four"  >
  <div class="container">

    <div class="main-title">
      <div class="hometab-heading box-heading">ABOUT US</div>
      <div class="title-sep"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item ">
      <div class="grid__item wide--two-thirds post-large--two-thirds large--two-thirds">

        <p>Anvi Jewellers founded by <b>Lavanya Ghulekar</b> in 2017 is a by-product of the passion for creativity of a home maker. Our vision is to build trust with high ethical standards, fair pricing and added value to our customers. We have made it our mission to strive every day to earn the confidence and trust of our clients by meeting and exceeding expectations of quality, service, and unsurpassed value. We expertise in all types of designer light-weight kundan, antique, c-zet, pearl jewellery etc. We make gold ornaments in 20 carat and 22 carat. Anvi Jewellers was founded with a refreshing and courageous objective to make beautiful jewellery accessible, affordable and forever. After 2 years of happy clients, Anvi Jewellers has finally launched online.  Anvi provides our clients with more than they imagined and less than they anticipated.</p>
        <div class="invisible-medium"></div>

        <div style="margin-top:52px;" class="grid__item ">

          <div  class="grid__item wide--one-third post-large--one-third large--one-third medium--one-half small--grid__item">

            <img id="see" src="images\a1.jpg" height="259.95" width="239.95" alt="" title="" />

          </div>


          <div  class="grid__item wide--one-third post-large--one-third large--one-third medium--one-half small--grid__item">

            <img id="seep" src="images\a11.jpg" height="259.95" width="239.95" alt="" title="" />

          </div>

          <div  class="grid__item wide--one-third post-large--one-third large--one-third medium--one-half small--grid__item">

            <img id="seel" src="images\a3.jpg" height="259.95" width="239.95" alt="" title="" />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now the problem is, it is working in localhost but when I uploaded it to server it is not hiding the div. Here is my website link [website](http://anvijewellers.com/index.html).

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem, please?

Comment: in your website i don't find any div with id="kingg".... and check your console browser because you have some js errors.

Comment: in my code it is there , but when i upload it in server it is not being displayed

Comment: I don't see any error please explain in details or check your media query

Comment: @Umashankar i dnt know, the div id which i gave is not displaying in the browser

Comment: probably you upload different files.

Comment: Create JSFiddle and add here

Comment: is that code within index.html?

Comment: sometimes cache makes issue to render your changes. please clear cache and try once. so you can be sure. there is problem with rendering or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through your source code online, this is what you actually have, inline:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #kingg img { display: none !important; }

}
</style>
```

This is working as expected, hiding the image in that div.
So the code you posted is bound to work, as it doesn't seem to have any syntax errors or anything.

So i would say to make sure you are uploading the file you are editing or edit the file in the server directly.

Answer (score 0):

use correct id or class. Use the code below to hide text.

```
.grid__item p:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```